# Check the status of server 1, if it is not available then run the scripts?

Tags: networking, server, bash, scripts, cron

I have 2 servers: 1 master with 1 slave and have a script which is running every 1 minute on the slave to check the availability of the master.

It should run always:

```
* * * * * /data/BackupServer/StatusCheck.bash  >> /data/BackupServer/Output.log 2>&1
```

Background: Master is responsible to run scripts in the background using crontab.

What I want is:

1. If the master is not available then the slave should add those responsibilities to its crontab to take over the master.
2. If the master is available again, the slave should `rm` these crontab configurations and hand over its duties to master again, if it has any.

What I have is:

```
#!/bin/bash
check=$(curl -s -w "%{http_code}\n" -L "master" -o /dev/null)
if [[ $check == 200 || $check == 403 ]]
then
    # Service is online
    echo "Service is online, slave is handing over the tasks to master if any"
    exit 0
else
    # Service is offline or not working correctly
    echo "Service is offline or not working correctly, slave is taking over master now"
    exit 1
fi
```

What I need is:

When the server is not available, the slave should start manually some of the scripts which are running in crontab of the master. But, here am not adding them in to crontab, instead asking the script to run only if the server is not available.

Can somebody suggest me a way how can I do this process automated in bash. I am not asking someone to write complete code for me, as am not familiar with the concepts need some help.

E.G. Can I do something as below ?

```
       #!/bin/bash
check=$(curl -s -w "%{http_code}\n" -L "master" -o /dev/null)
if [[ $check == 200 || $check == 403 ]]
then
    # Service is online
    echo "Service is online, slave is handing over the tasks to master if any"
    exit 0
else
    # Service is offline or not working correctly
    echo "Service is offline or not working correctly, slave is taking over master now"
    /manoj/scripts/location.plx > /manoj/logs/location/sync.log 2>&1
    /manoj/scripts/report.py > /manoj/logs/dashboard/dashboard.log 2>&1
    /etc/profile; /manoj/scripts/Space.py > /manoj/logs/dashboard/Consumption.log 2>&1
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I would prefer no crontab manipulation at all. Instead, I would simply run all the scripts on the slave every minute, but start each one with the check for the master's presence; then only run the rest of the script if the master doesn't answer.

Comment: @Jos in this case, the processes will be present in crontab on the slave, if the master is available master will also try to do the same, I t will lead to a overlapping right ?

Comment: If the master is available, the scripts will exit after the test.

Comment: @Jos That's not a comment!  *That's an answer!*  Please post an answer, ping me [at]Fabby and I'll come back and upvote! **;-)**

Comment: Thanks @Fabby, and relax ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do `crontab` manipulation.

Run scripts at both the master and the slave. On the slave, start each script with:

```
check=$(curl -s -w "%{http_code}\n" -L "master" -o /dev/null)
if [[ $check == 200 || $check == 403 ]]
then
#   master not available; do stuff
else
#   master is available, do nothing
    exit 0
fi
```

If the master is available, the scripts on the slave will exit after the test.

Comment: As promised!  **0:-)**  And I am relaxing: I'm making you do all the work!  **:D ;-) :D**

Comment: @Jos in this dont we use exit 1 in case of master is not available. I have already wrote something similar at the end of my question, can you check and let me know if that is what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but my point was to not modify the crontab on the fly, which you have now removed from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to have the same script running on both machines to reduce maintenance. Assuming the `/etc/hosts` file on the master contained the name "master" both machines could have the same script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function DoJobs () {
    /manoj/scripts/location.plx > /manoj/logs/location/sync.log 2>&1
    /manoj/scripts/report.py > /manoj/logs/dashboard/dashboard.log 2>&1
    /etc/profile; /manoj/scripts/Space.py > /manoj/logs/dashboard/Consumption.log 2>&1
}

# If master server run jobs and exit
if grep -q "Master" /etc/hosts ; then
    DoJobs
    exit 0
fi

# Not the master server so do jobs if it is down
check=$(curl -s -w "%{http_code}\n" -L "master" -o /dev/null)
if [[ $check == 200 || $check == 403 ]]
then
    # Service is online
    echo "Service is online, slave is handing over the tasks to master if any"
    exit 0
else
    # Service is offline or not working correctly
    echo "Service is offline or not working correctly, slave is taking over master now"
   DoJobs
   exit 1
fi
```

Now there is only a single script to maintain for both servers. When a new job is setup only one file has to be edited.